# MySQL check table exists with IF function

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT IF((
    SELECT COUNT(TABLE_NAME)
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='database0' AND TABLE_NAME='table'
) >0 , (
    SELECT id 
    FROM database1.table 
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM database0.table)
), NULL) AS pk_value;
```

The table `database0.table` may not exist; if the table does not exist, I want to skip the `true` clause of the `IF` statement. Even when the `IF` statement should return `NULL`, I get the error that `database0.table` does not exist. What can I do so that the query returns `NULL` instead of throwing an error if the table does not exist?

Comment: The query is compiled as a whole, this means the `IF` function doesn't act like an `IF` statement in a procedural language. If the table doesn't exist, the query won't compile successfully no matter what the `IF` function does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, queries are error-checked before they are run, so referring to a non-existent table won't work. You can store it as a function, which is only evaluated at run-time:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_pk;
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION get_pk()
RETURNS INT

BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT;
    DECLARE pk_value INT;

    SELECT COUNT(table_name) INTO counter
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'database0' AND table_name = 'table';

    IF counter = 1 THEN
        SELECT id INTO pk_value
        FROM database1.table 
        WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM database0.table);
    ELSE
        SELECT NULL INTO pk_value;
    END IF;

    RETURN pk_value;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Then access the value like this:

```
SELECT get_pk();
```